# Joining 3 tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have three models

Student;
AssessmentScores - (has many assessment, has many students);
Assessment

I need to select students who satisfy certain condition and their corresponding scores in a particular assessment type.

I tried the following query but rails keep joining the two tables and creating a new table.

`AssessmentScore.joins(:assessment).where(assessments: {my condition}).includes(:student).where(students: {my condidtion})`

when I execute this command on console, it is creating a new table assessment_scores_training and throwing table not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made some mistakes in has_many through relationship and changed the query to

```
AssessmentScore.includes(:student).where(students: {condition}).joins(:assessment).where(assessments:{condition})
```